# How to pass multiple rows as json in php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, mysqli

I'm trying to pass row details as JSON. How can one separate the selected columns from the query

```
$SQLTask = "
SELECT priority
     , task_name AS title
     , task_description AS description
     , start_date AS start
     , end_date AS end 
  FROM t_tasks
"; -- removed extraneous semi-colon
    $RESULT_Task = mysqli_query( $conn, $SQLTask );
            
    while($ROW_TASK = mysqli_fetch_assoc($RESULT_Task)) 
    {
        $TASK_NAME = $ROW_TASK['title'];

        $TASK_DESC = $ROW_TASK['description'];

        $TASK_START = $ROW_TASK['start'];

        $TASK_END = $ROW_TASK['end'];

    }
   

        $TASK_DETAILS[] = array('title' => $TASK_NAME, 'description' => $TASK_DESC, 'start' => $TASK_START, 'end' => $TASK_END); 

mysqli_close($conn);

echo json_encode($TASK_DETAILS);
```

Tried it in the format below and it worked but I need to use the priority column for other queries.
The JSON is to feed a calendar and show events.

````
<?php 
require('../classes/class_connect.php');

$Project_ID = $_GET['id'];

    $SQLTask = "SELECT task_name AS title, task_description AS description, start_date AS start, end_date AS end FROM t_tasks WHERE project_id = " . $Project_ID . "";
    $RESULT_Task = mysqli_query( $conn, $SQLTask );
            
    while($ROW_TASK = mysqli_fetch_assoc($RESULT_Task)) 
    {
        $TASK_ARRAY[] = $ROW_TASK;

        // if($ROW_TASK['priority'] == 'Low')
        // {
        //     $eventClassNames = "bg-light-secondary";
        // }
        // else if($ROW_TASK['priority'] == 'Normal')
        // {
        //     $eventClassNames = "bg-light-primary";
        // }
        // else if($ROW_TASK['priority'] == 'High')
        // {
        //     $eventClassNames = "bg-light-warning";
        // }
        // else if($ROW_TASK['priority'] == 'Urgent')
        // {
        //     $eventClassNames = "bg-light-danger";
        // }

        // array_push($TASK_ARRAY,$eventClassNames);
    }
    mysqli_close($conn);

               
echo json_encode($TASK_ARRAY);```
````

Comment: Please show an example of json output

Comment: See about sql injection and the importance of prepared and bound queries

Comment: The json output only shows one row ```[{"title":"Test Task","description":"This is a test task","start":"2021-02-19","end":"2021-02-20"}]```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add any data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](https://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or data *of any kind* directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: All-caps variable names are unusual. `$TASK_ARRAY` comes across as some kind of constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure whether I have clearly understood your question and what you want to achieve  as to "How can one separate the selected columns from the query".

But as for the second part you illustrated since all you wanted was priority field you could drop all other fields from the query. Also you could add the eventClassNames within the query.

Try to use mysqli's fetch_all and see how it works. For the first part then you wouldn't have to loop through the result set to create an array unless there was further processing to the array https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php

```
$SQLTask = "SELECT priority,
                   case priority
                      when 'Low' then 'bg-light-secondary'
                      when 'Normal' then 'bg-light-primary'
                      when 'High' then 'bg-light-warning'
                      when 'Urgent' then 'bg-light-danger'
                   end AS eventClassName
            FROM t_tasks WHERE project_id = " . $Project_ID . "";
$RESULT_Task = mysqli_query( $conn, $SQLTask );
$TASK_ROWS=$RESULT_TASK->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

$TASK_ARRAY=array_column($TASK_ROWS,'eventClassName');

echo json_encode($TASK_ARRAY);
```

Comment: @WaihuraMaina On your comment to the question you mentioned the JSON output having only one row, that is because you declared the $TASK_ARRAY within the while loop so it is initialized ever time, declare it before the lop $TASK_ARRAY=Array(), then populate it with array_push($TASK_ARRAY,$eventClassNames); within the loop as you have done.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}

$query = "SELECT Name, CountryCode FROM City ORDER by ID LIMIT 3";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);

/* numeric array */
$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);
printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row[0], $row[1]);

/* associative array */
$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row["Name"], $row["CountryCode"]);

/* associative and numeric array */
$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH);
printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row[0], $row["CountryCode"]);

/* free result set */
$result->free();

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

`echo json_encode($row)`

Ref:https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php